# Complementary vector using std::vector

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, std

I am writting in C++ an existing Matlab library. There is in Matlab a tilde operator, and `~vec` is the binary vector with 1s where `vec` is zero and 0s elsewhere.

More precisely, I have these lines of code in Matlab

```
        allDepthIdx = [1:nVec]'; 
        goodIdx = allDepthIdx(~offVec);
        goodValues = vec(~offVec);
```

I am looking for an efficient way to find the indices  `goodIdx = allDepthIdx(~offVec);`. I there a way, using `std::vector`, to find the list of indices which are in `1..nVec` and not in `offVec` ?

Comment: In Matlab-speak, this is called [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1). `offVec` is an array of [logicals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html), or double `0` or `1` values.

Comment: you might not want to copy matlab to c one to one. some things tend to work differently in c/c++. logical indexing is one of these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution, feel free to comment, or to propose yours !

```
        // First, I sort offVec
        std::sort(offVec.begin(), offVec.end());
        int k(0), idx(-1);

        std::vector<real32_T> goodDepthIdx;
        std::vector<real32_T> goodVal;

        // For j in 1..nVec, I check if j is in offVec
        for (int j = 0; j < nVec; j++)
        {
            k = 0;
            idx = offVec.at(k);

            // I go through offVec as long as element is strictly less than j
            while (idx < j)
            {
                idx = offVec.at(k++);
            }

            if (idx != j) // idx not in offElemsVec
            {
                goodDepthIdx.push_back(j); // Build vector with indices 
                                           // in 1..nVec not in offVec
                goodVal.push_back(vec.at(j)); // Build vector with values
                                           // at these indices
            }
        }
```